# Error while testing DecisionTreeClassifier in Scikit Learn with Python

Tags: python, types, tree, crash, scikit-learn

I read data in from a csv file, the first line is strings and the rest are all decimals. I had to convert the data from this file from a string to a decimal and am now trying to run a decision tree classifier over this data. I can train the data just fine but when I call DecisionTreeClassifier.score() I get the error message: "unknown is not supported"

here is my code:

```
cVal = KFold(len(file)-1, n_folds=10, shuffle=True);
for train_index, test_index in cVal:
    obfA_train, obfA_test = np.array(obfA)[train_index], np.array(obfA)[test_index]
    tTime_train, tTime_test = np.array(tTime)[train_index], np.array(tTime)[test_index]
    model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    model = model.fit(obfA_train.tolist(), tTime_train.tolist())
    print model.score(obfA_test.tolist(), tTime_test.tolist())
```

I filled obfA and tTime with these lines earlier:

```
tTime.append(Decimal(file[i][11].strip('"')))
obfA[i-1][j-1] = Decimal(file[i][j].strip('"'))
```

so obfA is a 2D array and tTime is 1D. Previously I tried removing the "tolist()" in the above code, but it did not affect the error. Here is the error report it prints:

```
in <module>()
---> print model.score(obfA_test.tolist(), tTime_test.tolist())

in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    """
    from .metrics import accuracy_score
 -->return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)

in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
  ->y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_clf_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    if y_type == 'multilabel-indicator':
        score = (y_pred != y_true).sum(axis=1) == 0

in _check_clf_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    if (y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator", "multilabel-sequences"]):
        -->raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
    if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:

ValueError: unknown is not supported
```

I added print statements to check the dimensions of the input parameters this is what it printed:

```
obfA_test.shape: (48L, 12L)
tTime_test.shape: (48L,)
```

I am confused why the error report shows 3 required parameters for score() but the documentation only has 2. What is the "self" parameter? Can anyone help me solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the problem I was having was because I was trying to use a DecisionTreeClassifier to predict continuous values, when they can only be used to predict discrete values. I will have to switch to using a regression model instead.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be reminiscent of the error [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234851/valueerror-unknown-is-not-supported-in-sklearn-rfecv). The problem seems to stem from the datatype you're using to fit and score the model. Instead of `Decimal` when filling your input data arrays, try `float`. And just so I don't have an inaccurate answer -- you can't use floats/continuous values for DecisionTreeClassifiers. If you want to use floats, use a DecisionTreeRegressor. Otherwise, try using integers or strings (but that might steering away from the task that you're trying to accomplish).

As for the self question at the end, this is a syntactic idiosyncrasy of Python. When you do model.score(...), Python is sort of treating it like score(model, ...). I'm afraid I don't know much more about it than that right now, but it isn't necessary to answer your original question. [Here's an answer that better addresses that particular question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: I changed everything from Decimal to float, but it changed the error from "unknown is not supported" to "continuous is not supported"

Comment: It would be helpful to have a better understanding of what you want to do. In your main question, can you briefly describe obfA and tTime? I just realized that you may not be able to use floats for DecisionTreeClassifier, but you may find it more useful to use DecisionTreeRegressor, depending upon your task.